# <copyField> issue on solr server

Tags: solr

I have one field on my SOLR,

```
<field name="term" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

but i need to change type of this field to 'string_ci'(this one is custom made type as for my concern) to 'string'. and as i have lots of records in my SOLR server i can't change this type directly. so for that i have add new field,

```
<field name="termNew" type="string_ci" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

and also add one more field

```
<copyField source='term' dest='termNew'> .
```

my question is , will it update all my already existed records after add this `<copyField>` tag?

Comment: No it won't, you should consider to reindex the documents.

Comment: I can't update whole  data on server as it is bunch of. Do you have any alternate option for this, all i need is to change type of term to 'string_ci' without loss of all my existed records.?

Comment: Atomic Updates is a feature added in Solr 4.0 that allows you to update on a field level rather than on a document level.

Comment: Atomic updates _do_ require all fields to be stored, and since at least this field isn't, I'm guessing that will be hard to do.

Comment: @MatsLindh, yeah, but as of now unfortunately this one is only the way from my point of view. anyways thanks to all for showing your inters in my query.

Answer (score 2):

No, you have to re-index the whole collection/core.